# Is it possible in JavaScript to get unique references to unique DOM elements (for use as unique keys in an object)?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, reference

While attempting to make my own methods for two-way data binding, I thought I'd had a great idea. As part of that idea, I tried to use DOM element references as keys in a JavaScript object that would hold data related to each element.

Unfortunately, it seems that JavaScript references to DOM elements are generic (with respect to a tagName [like p]).

For example:

```js
function testScenarios(){
  // create references to DOM objects
  var a = document.getElementById("id_a"),
      b = document.getElementById("id_b");
  
  // create and fill a test object
  var testObj = {};
  testObj[a] = "a"; // use the reference to p#id_a as a key for the value "a"
  testObj[b] = "b"; // use the reference to p#id_b as a key for the value "b"
  testObj[a.id] = "aId"; // use the id captured from the reference to p#id_a as a key for the value "aID"
  testObj[b.id] = "bId"; // use the id captured from reference to p#id_b as a key for the value "bId"
  testObj["0"] = a;  // use "0" as a key for a value that is the reference to p#id_a
  testObj["1"] = b; // use "1" as a key for a value that is the reference to p#id_b

  // store test values
  var testResults = {
    does_a_equal_b : (a===b),
    does_aId_equal_bId : (a.id===b.id),
    does_objA_equal_objB : (testObj[a]===testObj[b]),
    does_objAid_equal_objBid : (testObj[a.id]===testObj[b.id]),
    does_obj0_equal_obj1 : (testObj["0"]===testObj["1"]),
    what_is_a : a,
    what_is_b : b
  }
  
  // run the tests and display results
  for(testKey in testResults){
    document.getElementById(testKey).innerHTML = testResults[testKey];
  }
  document.getElementById("the_object").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(testObj, null, 4);
}
```

```css
p {width:400px;}
p:nth-child(odd){background:#ccc;}
span {float:right; font-weight:800;}
p:nth-child(8){background:#c63;}
p:nth-child(10){background:#c63; height:40px;}
p:nth-child(11){background:#c63; height:40px;}
p:nth-child(12){background:#c63; height:60px;}
```

```html
<p id="id_a">paragraph element a</p>
<p id="id_b">paragraph element b</p>
<button onclick="testScenarios()">Run the tests</button>
<p>a === b? (expecting false)<span id="does_a_equal_b"></span></p>
<p>a.id === b.id? (expecting false)<span id="does_aId_equal_bId"></span></p>
<p>testObj[a.id] === testObj[b.id]? (expecting false)<span id="does_objAid_equal_objBid"></span></p>
<p>testObj["0"] === testObj["1"]? (expecting false)<span id="does_obj0_equal_obj1"></span></p>
<p>testObj[a] === testObj[b]? (expecting false)<span id="does_objA_equal_objB"></span></p>
<p>ok, but... why?</p>
<p>What is a? (expecting somethihng like p#id_a, or a number)<span id="what_is_a"></span></p>
<p>What is b? (expecting somethihng like p#id_a, or a number)<span id="what_is_b"></span></p>
<p>What is testObj?<span id="the_object"></span></p>
<p>Sooooo... even though:<br>a !== b,<br>testObj[a] === testObj[b].<br>?¯\_(ツ)_/¯?<br><br>Is there some way to get the unique aspects of references a and b out of those references for later use?</p>
```

Is there a method for obtaining unique identifiers associated with each reference to a DOM object?

Comment: Object keys have to be strings. Converting an object to a string results in a string like `[Object typename]`, where `typename` is the object's prototype name.

Comment: So all your keys are things like `[Object HTMLLIElement]` or `[Object HTMLDivElement]"`

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I agree and understand that objects require strings as key names. I also kinda understand that a reference to a DOM object shows itself as a string like [Object typename]... but I wanna believe (since the reference itself can differentiate between objects) that there is accessible and unique info stored in the reference, or info that could be accessed when the reference was initially stored... and that such info could be converted to a string (if it isn't already a string) and that it would be unique and usable as a key. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WeakMap's are really handy for this.

There similar to Map's, but will get removed & garbage collected when the Element is destroyed.

Below is a simple working snippet.  For testing purposes I'm just creating a simple generated string that I attach to the element.  Then from the click handler I'm reading this info back.  The value can be objects too, for a more complicated data structure.

```js
const data = new WeakMap();

let count = 0;
for (const el of document.querySelectorAll("div")) {
  count += 1;
  data.set(el, `This is data for item ${count}`);
}

document.body.addEventListener("click", evt => {
  const info = data.get(evt.target);
  if (info) document.querySelector("#clicked").innerText = info;
});
```

```css
div { 
  border: 1px solid black; 
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="items">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
  <div>four</div>
</div>
<div id="clicked"></div>
```

Comment: Just when I thought maps were the coolest "new" thing, here comes Keith with weakmaps!
Really appreciate this answer and how you tied it to eventListeners (and thus to two-way data binding)!
Of course, just like with CertainPerformance's map answer, I feel like this is a workaround to finding whatever unique information exists inside a reference, and that it is a great workaround... any ideas how to get that lower level reference info so that I could use regular ol objects and pump a string representing the unique reference into an object's key position?

Comment: No problem.  There very handy, you can use them for private data in classes etc.  I use them all the time.  There is also WeakSet's too.  In both cases the key's need to be reference types like objects & Dom nodes, as that's what controls the garbage collection..

Comment: @user2551523  `use regular ol objects and pump a string representing the unique reference into an object's key position?`  I'm not 100% sure what you mean here, are you wanting a unique reference to a DOM node as in a string.  If so you could use the WeakMap to keep a reference that increments, then assign the id to the DOM's data-attribute.   So with only a string, you could first find the element by it's data-attribute, and then find the private data using the WeakMap to the DOM.

Comment: Thanks again @Keith. I am still holding out hope that there is some, accessible, unique info stored within a reference. I am sure it is obvious that I don't really understand how references work, but, since they are able to point to unique DOM objects, they must somehow contain unique info, no?
If references are discernable only by their position in memory, is there a safe way to access ino related to that memory location?

Comment: if I did:
var a = document.getElementById("a_id");
var x = document.getElementById("a_id");
then
a === x would yield true because they reference the same object.
In each case, the strings representing a and x would be generic: [object HTMLParagraphElement].
But, with:
var b = document.getElementById("b_id");
a === b would yield false because a and b reference different objects.
Nonetheless, both a and b's string representation would be [object HTMLParagraphElement]
... so... what and where is the information that lets a and b know they are referencing different elements?

Comment: If this was C++ / C, then you would have something called a pointer.  But Javascript  doesn't have the concept of pointers, it only has references.  Internally the JS Weakmap might be using pointers behind the scenes, but this is something that's not exposed to the JS engine.  But giving something a unique id, is not that complicated.  There are also JS libs for generating GUID's.  In summary, I don't know of any unique id's that are given to DOM nodes.

Comment: Well, darn. And yet, thanks again for the weakmaps solution!

Answer (score 1):

Javascript object keys are always *strings*, so if `a` is an element, `testObj[a]` won't work, because the element will be coerced to a string, which may well have the same value as some other element's coerced string. Use a `Map` instead, which is similar to an object, but can have keys of *any value*, including HTMLElements:

```js
// create references to DOM objects
var a = document.getElementById("id_a"),
  b = document.getElementById("id_b");

// create and fill a test object
const map = new Map();
map.set(a, 'a');
map.set(b, 'b');
map.set(a.id, "aId");
map.set(b.id, "bId");
map.set('0', a);
map.set('1', b);
map.set(a.id, "aId");

// store test values
var testResults = {
  does_a_equal_b: (a === b),
  does_aId_equal_bId: (a.id === b.id),
  does_objA_equal_objB: (map.get(a) === map.get(b)),
  does_objAid_equal_objBid: (map.get(a.id) === map.get(b.id)),
  does_obj0_equal_obj1: (map.get('0') === map.get('1')),
  what_is_a: a,
  what_is_b: b
};
console.log(testResults);
```

```html
<p id="id_a">paragraph element a</p>
<p id="id_b">paragraph element b</p>
```

Comment: Many thanks CertainPerformance for pointing me in the direction of maps!
I feel like this is a workaround to finding whatever unique information exists inside a reference, but also that it is a great workaround. Thanks again!
(ps... moved the answer to the weakmap suggestion by Keith because of garbage collection... which I am blindly assuming to be true.)

Answer (score 0):

You could traverse the DOM and add a unique classname to everything.

```
j = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < document.body.childNodes.length; i++) {
  document.body.childNodes[i].classList.add("__j" + j++); 
}
```

You'll want to do that recursively to get children of children.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and recognize that I could put unique information into each element that I could then use to reference that element.
What I am looking for is some way to get unique information out of a reference itself. Somehow, javascript knows that {}!=={} for testObj["0"] and testObj["1"]... how does it know that? Where is that info stored?

Comment: That's a pretty low level thing. When you set a variable it goes into memory. When you read a variable, under the hood, JavaScript says "where is the variable stored in memory", and then reads the memory there. When you do {}==={} those are two objects stored in memory, and JavaScript says "are these objects pointing to the same piece of memory". If they point to two different memory locations, then they aren't the same object.

Comment: That said using a map is the right way. I actually didn't even realize JavaScript had maps. The other answer is the right one.